# Assign empty slice without referring to its type?

Tags: go, slice, type-inference

My code calls a library function which looks roughly like this:

```
func Search() ([]myLibrary.SomeObject, error) {
    var results []apiv17.SomeObject
    // ...
    if (resultsFound) {
      results = append(results, someResult)
    }
    return results
}
```

...and my code calls it and then marshals it to JSON.

```
results, err := myLibrary.Search()
bytes, err := json.Marshal(results)
```

Now the problem is that because of the way the `Search` function is written (and let's assume we can't change it), it'll return an uninitialized `nil` slice if there are no results. And unfortunately, there is no way to configure `encoding/json` to encode nil slices as `[]` (see e.g. this [proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37711) with ongoing discussion).

Explicitly checking for `nil` solves the problem:

```
results, err := myLibrary.Search()
if results == nil {
  results = []apiv17.SomeObject{}
}
bytes, err := json.Marshal(results)
```

...but it also adds an explicit dependency on the return type, `apiv17.SomeObject`. That's inconvenient because that type frequently changes in the library. E.g. in the next library version it might be `apiv18.SomeObject`.

With the `nil` check above, I'll have to update my code every time that happens.

Is there any way to avoid this and assign an empty, non-nil slice to the variable without explicitly referring to its type? Something like this:

```
results = [](type of results){}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Go 1.18

You can use a generic function that captures the slice's base type and returns a slice of length zero:

```
func echo[T any](v []T) []T {
    return make([]T, 0)
}

func main() {
    n := foo.GetFooBar()
    if n == nil {
        n = echo(n) // no need to refer to apiv17 here
    }
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(n)
    fmt.Println(string(bytes)) // prints []
}
```

The purpose of requiring a regular argument `v []T` in `echo` is to allow type inference to unify the slice `[]apiv17.SomeObject` with the argument `[]T` and infer `T` as the base type `apiv17.SomeObject`, so that you can call it just as `echo(n)` and no explicit type parameter.

The package `apiv17` is of course known at compile time because it's transitively imported via `myPackage`, so you can take advantage of this and type inference to avoid adding an explicit `import` statement for `apiv17`.

This is how it looks like on the multi-file playground: https://go.dev/play/p/4ycTkaGLFpo

The type is declared in `bar` package, but `main` only imports `play.ground/foo` and only uses `foo.GetFooBar`.

---

#### Go 1.17 and below

Reflection. Just change the `echo` function from above to taking an `interface{}` argument (there's no `any` in Go 1.17, remember?) and do the deed with [`reflect.MakeSlice`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#MakeSlice):

```
func set(v interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if rv.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        panic("not a ptr")
    }
    reflect.Indirect(rv).Set(reflect.MakeSlice(rv.Type().Elem(), 0, 0))
}
```

Then pass a pointer to the slice, so that you can set its value with reflection.

```
func main() {
    n := foo.GetFooBar()
    if n == nil {
        set(&n)
    }
    fmt.Printf("type: %T, val: %v, is nil: %t\n", n, n, n == nil)
    // type: []bar.FooBar, val: [], is nil: false
    
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(n)
    fmt.Println(string(bytes)) // prints [] again
}
```

Go 1.17 playground: https://go.dev/play/p/4jMkr22LMF7?v=goprev

Comment: Outstanding, thank you very much! I'm on 1.18 and the generic `echo` function works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer describes how to create an empty slice.

But you can solve your *original* issue much simpler: if `results` is `nil`, you don't need to create a empty slice, regardless of whatever element type it would have, the JSON marshaling would be `[]` anyway. So if `results` is `nil`, no need to call `json.Marshal()`, just "output" `[]`:

```
results, err := myLibrary.Search()
var bytes []byte
if results == nil {
    bytes = []byte{'[', ']' } // JSON marshaling result is "[]"
} else {
    bytes, err = json.Marshal(results)
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Great response, thanks! You're absolutely right, this solves the original issue as stated in my question. Turns out, my [mcve] is a bit too minimal. For my real world problem, the result doesn't actually get marshaled right away but instead passed around a few times.